# {error_message: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs

Tags: android, flutter, api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I have billing account in google cloud platform and I generate api key  and used in my flutter project but its giving that error.

**error :** "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, predictions: [], status: REQUEST_DENIED"

I add my key in android/app/src/main/androidmanifest.xm
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1lyb.png)